# Unity 2D and UI rendering issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

[image: game picture]

I have been developing a game for a little while now and have started to notice rendering issues with the Unity3D engine. The poop emoji is supposed to appear in front of the floor tile but this isn't the case here. There are more depending on how you position the camera. They are both on the default layer and I have no idea what the cause would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If multiple sprite are on the same `sorting layer` and the same `order in layer` index you cant be sure which one will be on top of others. It could change anytime depending of the camera position or even on game session.

To be sure of your rendering , use the `order in layer` and set a higher value to the emoji than the floor.

[image: layer order example]

*Note : I use the 2020.2.0b unity version. Your inspector could look different but the `Order in Layer` should be there.*

Comment: Thank you for the response and this solved my problem for the emoji, but I have another character that seems to glitch through the wall. [https://prnt.sc/uyz51j](https://prnt.sc/uyz51j)

Comment: Did your wall is a sprite too ? Without more information it's hard to tell.

Comment: Yes, they are all sprites.

Comment: Without having more information about your sprite order I cant help you

Comment: The characters are 0, the floor is -1.

Comment: And what about the wall?

Comment: The wall sprite is 0.

Comment: This is why your character could go through the wall. They have the same order. Be sure the character order is greater than the floor AND the wall.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpfulness throughout this but this can't work for me as there are times in the game where the wall is in front of the character so this wouldn't work. I've been able to fix this by converting the sprites to mesh renderers, so if anyone stumbles across this post, do that.